# Why is my output not showing the node containing 14 when I print?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, insert, singly-linked-list

Why is my output not showing the node containing `14` when I print it?

I guess I am missing some crucial principles in implementing a linked list:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct ListNode
{
    int value;
    ListNode *next;
    ListNode(int d,ListNode* p=NULL) //constructor
    {
        value=d;
        next=p;
    }
};

int main()
{
    ListNode* header=NULL;
    header=new ListNode(5);
    ListNode* ptr=header; //pointer to find the correct position

    ListNode* sptr=new ListNode(13);
    header->next=sptr;
    ListNode* tptr=new ListNode(19);
    sptr->next=tptr;
    ListNode* t=new ListNode(14);
    while((ptr->value) < (t->value))
    {
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }

    ListNode* g=ptr;
    ptr=t;
    t->next=g;

    while(header!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<header->value<<" ";
        header=header->next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's unclear from your code what you want to achieve. You've implemented the ListNode item just fine, although you would probably make it a template so you're not bound to use ints as values.

In any case the "t" variable is never added to your original list so you cannot ever print it.
Add comments to the code to make your intent clear. Usually this also helps yourself to figure out what's wrong. See also rubber duck debugging: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Comment: You're pointing `ptr` at `ListNode(14)`, but you're not pointing `ListNode(13)->next` to `ListNode(14)`. You need one of the existing nodes' next pointer to point to your new node.

Comment: @Welbog Why is it necessary ? isn't ptr==sptr->next i.e. already pointing the address of node 13 to 14 node

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not add the node with the value 14 to the list. That is neither node in the list points to the node created in this declaration

```
 ListNode* t=new ListNode(14);
```

The only what you did is set the data member next of the node to the address of the node with the value 19.

```
ListNode* g=ptr;
ptr=t;
t->next=g;
```

Here the statement

```
ptr=t;
```

does not make an effect.

If after this loop

```
while(header!=NULL)
{
    cout<<header->value<<" ";
    header=header->next;
}
```

you will place this code snippet in your program

```
cout << '\n';

while ( ptr != NULL )
{
    cout<<ptr->value<<" ";
    ptr=ptr->next;
}
```

you will get the program output as

```
5 13 19 
14 19
```

To make it clear then pay attention to that after this loop

```
  while((ptr->value) < (t->value))
  {
    ptr=ptr->next;
  }
```

the pointer `ptr` points to the node with the value 19. And you can not use the pointer to insert the new node with the value 14 before this node because you have a singly-linked list and the node with the value 19 has only one reference to the next node.

So you can insert the new node with the value 14 only after the node with the value 19 using the pointer `ptr` obtained after the while loop.

If you want to insert the new node with the value 14 before the node with the value 19 then instead of this code snippet

```
  while((ptr->value) < (t->value))
  {
    ptr=ptr->next;
  }
  
ListNode* g=ptr;
ptr=t;
t->next=g;
```

you should write something like the following

```
  ListNode *prev = nullptr;   
  while( ptr != nullptr && ptr->value < t->value )
  {
    prev = ptr;
    ptr=ptr->next;
  }
  
  t->next = ptr;
  prev == nullptr ? header = t : prev->next = t;
```

Comment: " And you can not use the pointer to insert the new node with the value 14 before this node because you have a singly-linked list and the node with the value 19 has only one reference to the next node." Thanks for such a detailed answer but I am hopelessly stuck on understanding the quoted sentence. Why (ptr=t;) doesn't make any affect?

Comment: @WaqarAhmed You assigned the value of t to ptr. Now the two variables t and ptr have the same value that is they both point to the same node with the value 14. And what? What is the result of this assignment? How does it influence on the list?

Comment: Exactly! In my mind, once I assigned this I can use (t->next)  to point to the address of node containing 19 i.e. g pointer.. thereby linking the whole list. (I CAN'T UNDERSTAND HOW IS THIS WRONG)

Comment: @WaqarAhmed You assigned the data member next of the node pointed to by the pointer t with the address of the node that contains the value 19. But neither node in the list points to the new node with the value 14.

Comment: "But neither node in the list points to the new node with the value 14" Why?

Comment: @WaqarAhmed Because neither data member next of the nodes existed in list set to point to the new node. See the solution in my answer. Investigate it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for making my stagnant, dumpster to think. Now I can understand that by doing (ptr=t), I was actually overwriting the address of 19 node and was not updating this in 13's next member. Resultantly, I would print the same list over and over again. Phew!! that's a shame I didn't notice this. Heavily Obliged. Thanks again!!

Comment: @WaqarAhmed To close the question select the best answer.:)